# Generic Program received signal: “SIGABRT” with NSZombie ONLY on iOS SDK 4.0

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, sigabrt, nszombie

my project works on iphone/ipad sdk except SDK 4.0.

It crash with stupid `Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.`

I've activated NSZombie, Debug all lines, but nothing.
Debugger crash before `main()` in main.m and I not unable to solve the problem.

This is **main.h**:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppDelegate");
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

...and this is AppDelegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {    
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationFade];
  [window addSubview:viewController.view];
  [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

and this is my view Controller :)

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

This app use external library as **libz.dylib** and a **custom static lib myLib.a**.

Use **all of this frameworks**:

```
- QuartCore  
- CFNetwork  
- CoreLocation  
- UIKit  
- Foundation  
- CoreGraphics  
- SystemConfiguration
```

Is there a know issue to solve this problem?
I don't understand what is the casuse...

Any idea please?

thanks.

Comment: something tells me that custom static lib thingy might have something to do with it. of course, the code you show isn't going to crash..

Comment: @MiRAGe Uhm... i also suppose it's a problem from the static lib... but I'm investigating.

Comment: Try reset content and setting menu option in Iphone simulator. Also update the sdk to latest version.

Comment: What is myLib.a ? An Objective-C, C++ or C library ? Does it have any `+ (void)initialize` methods on your class ? My main guess is that the dynamic linker wants to resolve a symbol that's missing on iOS SDK 4.0.

Comment: There are a few magic variables for the dynamic linker, see [TN2239](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2239/_index.html) for a list. You can set them the same way you set `NSZombieEnabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved compiling myLib.a from 3.0+ with no CLLocationCoordinate2DMake (that not exist on sdk <4)!

thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to add `[super viewDidLoad]` in your `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
     [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: @Vaibhav No, there was a  [super viewDidLoad]; I forgotted in copy/paste.

Comment: hmm... then in this case, i would have did what you do when you are dealing with C language. Put NSLogs in all of your methods, so that you can come to know at which point your application is crashing, once you get that method, you can find which line is causing the crash.

Comment: @Vaibhav I'm NOT able to set a breackpoint in MAIN, neither in AppDelegate and in ViewController!! It crash before all of this!

Comment: hmm... no issues...i had many right answers which neva got positive votes and here I get one negative for nothing :)..neways... are you linking the static library properly in your project.

Comment: and you are not using XCode 4...very strange... try to clean all the targets, delete the app from simulator and run it again. If the libraries are linked fine, then there must be some problem in the code.

Comment: @Vaibhav Tekam: I didn't vote on your answer, but I imagine the negative vote was because your answer missed crucial points in the question, namely that the OP's program doesn't even start and thus can't reach the view controller.